# Animate the position of a DOM Node depending on a video's currentTime

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, html5-video

I have built a HTML 5 video player displaying meta-information as an overlay. The meta information should be displayed at a specific coordinate at a particular playing time of the video above the video canvas. The overlay position (CSS attributes top and left) should be animated linearly between these coordinates.

The positions provided by the user are stored in a JavaScript object. E.g.:

```
{
    "0.283079": {
        "x": 0.019623233908948195,
        "y": 0.05441860465116279
    },
    "10.302745": {
        "x": 0.49686028257456827,
        "y": 0.8869767441860466
    },
    "18.924348": {
        "x": 0.9657247514390371,
        "y": 0.08046511627906977
    }
}
```

To implement the animation of the overlay between `0.283079 s` and `18.924348 s` of the video, I linearly interpolated the values between the given timecodes, leading to the following result:

```
{
    0.3: {
        "x": 0.020429181741986834,
        "y": 0.05582461122653863
    },
    0.35: {
        "x": 0.022810683523910604,
        "y": 0.059979231448085354
    },
    0.4: {
        "x": 0.025192185305834374,
        "y": 0.06413385166963209
    },
    0.45: {
        "x": 0.027573687087758144,
        "y": 0.06828847189117881
    },
    0.5: {
        "x": 0.02995518886968191,
        "y": 0.07244309211272554
    },

    ...

    18.65: {
        "x": 0.95080501675582,
        "y": 0.1061291200719866
    },
    18.7: {
        "x": 0.9535241425892902,
        "y": 0.10145184817772868
    },
    18.75: {
        "x": 0.9562432684227602,
        "y": 0.09677457628347075
    },
    18.8: {
        "x": 0.9589623942562304,
        "y": 0.09209730438921293
    },
    18.85: {
        "x": 0.9616815200897006,
        "y": 0.087420032494955
    }
}
```

The idea behind this approach was simply to listen for the `timeupdate` event to subsequently use the rounded `currentTime` value as the key to access the object to retrieve the interpolated position.

However the `timeupdate` event fires all too seldom to achieve a fluid animation. (It fires every 250ms in chrome).

To compensate for this problem, I decided to use jQuery's `.animate()` to animate the movement in between `timeupdate` events:

```
    this.element.stop(true, true).animate({
        "left" : this.taggingPosition.x + "px",
        "top" : this.taggingPosition.y + "px"
    }, 250, "linear");
```

This approach lead to an animation that comes closer to what is intended. Unfortunately the animation is still far from fluid, given the fact that `timeupdate` might fire at irregular intervals. Experimenting with the `clearQueue` and `jumpToEnd` attributes of `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )` also didn't help in creating a more fluid animation.

How can a smooth animation be achieved?

Comment: Sounds like you should use a custom interval check and find the closest property to the current time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than wait for `timeupdate` or use `setInterval`, I recommend [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame), which is designed specifically for animation. It should fire approximately 60 times per second, give or take, depending on CPU load and other factors determined by the browser. It has the added benefit that the browser will usually synchronize it with repaints to avoid flickering and/or screen-tearing, which can happen on slower devices like phones.

Alternatively, you can use Popcorn.js with the [Popcorn Base](https://github.com/brianchirls/popcorn-base) add-on module, which more or less does exactly what you're trying to do. It has keyframe interpolation and various tweening functions built in. There's plenty of documentation and a few demos. I recommend using the 'style' plugin if you don't want to build your own.

Comment: The Popcorn Style Plugin took the hassle out of this task. I was able to reduce the animation logic to 10 lines. Thanks for saving me from reinventing the wheel!

Comment: That's great! Very glad to hear it.